# User profile disks on RDS deployment not working

Tags: rds, user-profile-disks

I have an RDS deployment that consists of several RDS Session Hosts and several collections.
Almost all collections are configured to use User profile disks, I have different file servers for storing the UPD disks. Each server has a shared folder, and inside the shared folder, a folder for each collection that uses that server.

Everything works well. From time to time, I have a problem with some user that has the problem of temporary profile, but I always solve it with the standard procedure of deleting the .bak registry key in profile list and deleting the temporary profiles created in the RDSH server.

Now, I have one collection called Red, with UPD poiting to \server1\userprofiles\RED1 (userprofiles is the shared folder), and another collection called Yellow UPD poiting to \server2\userprofiles\YELLOW1 (userprofiles is the shared folder).

As I say, everything works well. But now I need to create a collection called RED2, and a collection called YELLOW2. I have deployed one RDSH server for each one. I install the roles, add them to the farm, and create the folders \server1\userprofiles\RED2 and \server2\userprofiles\YELLOW2.

I create the collections, and set them each one to use the corresponding UPD. I assign one server to each collection, and when I press ok, the template VDHX is created under each folder, and I check that permissions are assigned properly: I compare the permissions in the shared folders and in the newly created folders and in the VDHX file and all servers have full control the same way that in all working folders.

And here begins the fun: New collections don't work. When I try to logon in any of them, I get the temporary profile message. Event viewer shows Event ID 1511 saying that it cannot find a local profile, thus creating a temporary profile.

I have even created a new shared folder for those new collections: same result. I have tried with fqdn, with IP... file server and shared folders are reacheable from connection brokers and from RDSH servers. RDSH servers are in same subnet that the ones that work in the other collections. I am out of ideas. Don't know what else test or try to make it work.

Any help?

Comment: Can you double check you gave the Read/Write rights to the Session Hosts on the shared folder (NTFS permissions, and Sharing permissions)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not only double (and tripple) checked Session Hosts have full control permission both NTFS and sharing in the shared folders and everything below, but I have granted Everyone group Full control both in NTFS and in sharing, and still have the issue.